# JavaScript - How to format this JSON this way?

Tags: javascript, json

I am wondering how to format the following JSON:

```
{  
    "names":{  
        "Nancy":[  
        ],
        "Charles":[  
        ]
    }
}
```

To the following one:

```
{  
    "names":{  
        0: Object
         "Nancy":[  
        ],
        1: Object
        "Charles":[  
        ]
    }
}
```

So far my code is:

```
for(var i=0; i < this.data.length; i++){  
    storeInfo[i] = this.data[i];
    var row = storeInfo[i];

    result.names[row.info] = result.names[row.info] || []; 
    result.names[row.info];
}
```

I am willing to retrieve data in this way `names[i]`, that way I need to convert it.

I think that in order to achieve the wanted result we need to have a set inside an array. By the end, we will be having multiple sets inside one array. Please advice if you have a better way to do it.

Comment: from where do you get a stable sort order of the keys?

Comment: The restructure doesn't make sense to me. *"I am willing to retrieve data in this way `names[i]`"* You can still do that with the existing data structure, if `i` has the correct value. Which problem are you *really* trying to solve by doing this? Lets focus on that.

Comment: @FelixKling well the `i` is an index number and I want to print the values inside by looping around, currently the `i` is a string value not a number, so I believe I can't run a for loop in order to retrieve the values inside, you got my meaning?

Comment: Where does `i`  (or rather `data`) come from? Object properties don't have an order so getting the `i`th property doesn't make much sense, even if you'd change it (because the order would be arbitrary). If you want to use `result.names[i]` instead in your above example, then the order of `this.data` and `result.names` would have to be the same. How can you guarantee that?

Comment: The `i` value will come from a for loop, as I need to display the values in a list, like `<li>` so, by the end I need only the string value, for that I think that I need to loop through the array to get it!

Comment: `data` comes from a REST API

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `names` is the only key in `data`:

```
var data = {
    "names":{
        "Nancy" : [1,2,3],
        "Charles" : [4,5,6],
        "Dingo" : [7, 8, 9]
    }
}

var i = 0;
for(var name in data.names)
{
    data.names[i] = {};
    data.names[i][name] = data.names[name];
    delete data.names[name];
    ++i;
}
```

At the end of this `data` will equal:

```
data = {
    "names" : {
        "0" : { "Nancy" : [1,2,3] },
        "1" : { "Charles" : [4,5,6] },
        "2" : { "Dingo" : [7, 8, 9] }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
data = {  
    "names":{  
        "Nancy":[  
        ],
        "Charles":[  
        ]
    }
}
```

You mean you want this?

```
{  
    "names":{  
        "0": { "Nancy":[  
        ] },
        "1": { "Charles":[  
        ] }
    }
}
```

So:

```
var result = { "names" : {} }

var keys = Object.keys(data.names);

for(var i=0; i < keys.length; i++){  
    obj = {};
    obj[keys[i]] = data.names[keys[i]];
    result.names[i] = obj; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although already answered by other people here but If it is just about printing the values in obj, you don't need to change the object. May be this can help,

```
var data ={  
    "names":{  
        "Nancy":[1,2],
        "Charles":[ 3,4 ]
    }
}

for(var obj in data.names){
    console.log(data.names[obj]);
}
```

fiddle --- https://jsfiddle.net/2dkn9ehn/